# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "dbuser"

Tags: java, docker-compose, psql, jdbi

So i have been trying to connect to a psql database that's in docker using jdbi connection.
And it always says that the password is incorrect even though I only set the password in two places of my app.

my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  db-tests:
    container_name: db-tests
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./tests/Dockerfile-db-test
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=dbuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=changeit
      - POSTGRES_DB=db
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

Where I try to connect to the bd

```
Jdbi.create(
    PGSimpleDataSource().apply {
        setURL("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db?user=dbuser&password=changeit")
    }
).configure()
```

Launch docker in cmd:

```
docker compose up --build --force-recreate
```

Docker Configuration:

[image]

login to the user dbuser

```
docker exec -ti db-tests bash

then

psql -U dbuser -d db

or

psql -U dbuser --password -d db
```

the first psql command just connects to the user in the cmd whithout asking for password.
the second psql command asks for password, and i can write whatever i want and it's always valid.

Why can't I connect to my BD using jdbi??

Answer (score 0):

The password is not set as a query parameter on the database URL. It is a separate property entirely.

Various examples I found online include:

```java
Jdbi jdbi = Jdbi.create("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db", "dbuser", "password");
try (Handle handle = jdbi.open()) {
    doStuffWith(handle);
}
```

or

```java
@Override
protected DataSource createDataSource() {
  final PGSimpleDataSource datasource = new PGSimpleDataSource();
  datasource.setServerName("localhost");
  datasource.setPortNumber(5432);
  datasource.setUser("dbuser");
  datasource.setPassword("password");
  datasource.setDatabaseName("db");
  datasource.setApplicationName("Test Database");
  return datasource;
}
```

Or

```java
PGSimpleDataSource pgSimpleDataSource = new PGSimpleDataSource();
pgSimpleDataSource.setBinaryTransfer(true);
pgSimpleDataSource.setApplicationName("geogig");
pgSimpleDataSource.setServerName("localhost");
pgSimpleDataSource.setPortNumber(5432);
pgSimpleDataSource.setDatabaseName("db");
pgSimpleDataSource.setUser("dbuser");
pgSimpleDataSource.setPassword("password");
```

No where is there any example where the password is set as a query param on the db url string.